# Pop_front doubly linked list function issue

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I got an issue with a function for popping out the element from the front of the bidirectional ring.

```
template <typename Key, typename Info>
void Ring<Key, Info>::pop_front() {
if (!isEmpty()) {

    Node* p = any->next;
    if (any != NULL) {
    p->prev->next = p->next;
    p->next->prev = p->prev;
    delete p;
    }}}
```

Function begin() is defined.
As you see, it should work perfectly but it doesn't start from the first element. It pops the second one. 
What to do? How to point to the first Node?

Comment: What is `any`?  Regardless of what it is, checking it for `NULL` **after** you've already dereferenced it is somewhat pointless.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: any works as a head

Answer (score 0):

Change `Node* p = any->next;` to  `Node* p = any;`

Comment: I receive some memory issues at the output then, I tried to do so.

Comment: @MartaK. - Linked-list manipulation code is guaranteed to be wrong unless you draw a diagram of what you're trying to achieve, and walk through it by hand.  So draw a diagram, and then figure out what your code is doing, by hand.  See the problem?